# Why Windows command Processor is exited after Opened the file in python?

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, wait, popen

I opened a file in python with the following code,

```
 s=subprocess.Popen(fileName,shell=True)
 s.wait()
 os.remove(fileName)
```

Whether the file is closed or not, it directly jumps to os.remove(), by that time file is not closed. So getting the following exception.

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

The above problem is occuring in other machine, but in my machine until the file is closed code flow is not coming to os.remove()

How can I make subprocess.Popen() should wait until the file is closed.

Comment: you might want `os.startfile(filename)` or `webbrowser.open(filename)` instead. You could also specify the associated program explicitly: `subprocess.check_call([program, filename])`

Comment: Hi J.F. Sebastian, I tried with both os.startfile(filename) and webbrowser.open(filename) ways. With these 2 ways file is opening, but here we could not track when the file is closed. With subprocess.check_call([program, filename]) we can able to open the file and also we can track the event when file is closed. This is working in my system, but in other machine I could not track  the file closed event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried in the Different way as follows,

```
def removeTempFile(tempFileName):
  f = None
  while f == None:
   try:
       f=open(tempFileName,'w')
       f.close()
   except Exception as e:
       print "already open"
       f=None
       time.sleep(2)

os.remove(tempFileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the value of `fileName` this is a bit of a guess, but I believe your problem is that you are waiting for the shell to exit, but the shell starts another process to open the file and doesn't wait for that process to exit.

For example, if you try to open an Excel spreadsheet this way, the shell will lookup the registry and determine that the way to open a spreadsheet is to run Excel (if not already running) with a command line flag that prevents it creating a blank worksheet, and then send it a DDE command to tell it to open the worksheet. The shell then exits, your `wait` completes, but the file is still open (or may even not yet have opened).

If you want to wait for completion you need at the very least to run the actual command that opens the file, and not depend on the shell's automated lookup. That may still not be enough if the application is already running as some applications may detect an existing instance so your wait would only work if the application is not already running.

There probably isn't any simple clean way to do what you want. The best I can suggest is that if the `os.remove()` call fails you use a polling loop, sleep for 1 second and then try again, but you may still have problems if the file hasn't actually been opened by the time the `wait()` call completes.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try something like this:

```
s=subprocess.Popen(fileName,shell=True)

while True:
    try:
        os.remove(filename)
        break
    except(WindowsError):
        time.sleep(1) # wait 1 second

....
```

This snippet should try repeatedly to close the file. If it gets the windows error, it waits for a second before it tries again.